# Skip SSL verification using CURL for subsequent requests to same URI

Tags: ssl, web, curl

Is it possible to skip SSL verification entirely for a GET request while using curl?

I tried `-k or --insecure` option but the verbose (-v) showed the verification was done but the result was ignored.

Tried using `curl --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies.txt -X GET --user UN:PW -H "Content-Type: application/json" --insecure <URI> -v` but I saw '/tmp/cookies.txt' was not created, but the subsequent requests also verified the certificate.

PS: I want to get the time taken for ~50 requests (to same URI) without the SSL verification done for each request every time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. What difference does it make in your use case between ignoring certificate errors and not checking certificate in the first place? The SSL verification is fast and purely local and the time to do this is practically irrelevant compared to process startup, network traffic, key exchange and output.

Comment: I recomend you to try it directly on a hosting. You could search for free hostings or cheap hostings. So you could install SSL with Let's Encrypt for Free.

Comment: I wanted to save the small overhead due to this SSL verification.